# Trying to add font awesome icon via jQuery or JavaScript and make phone number clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, content-management-system

I am working with a CMS. This is the HTML which I can not edit. A client has requested I add a second name and phone number to the footer of his website. I've been able to add the second person's name and phone number. I am however stuck on how to add the fa fa-phone font awesome phone icon and how to make the phone number clickable. I can not edit the html. I have to do it with jQuery or vanilla JavaScript.

```
    <div class="jls-agent container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="agent-signature-data" class="jls-agent-contact col-xs-7">
      <h2 class="jls-agent-name"><strong>Second Person</strong></h2>
      <p></p>
      <a href="tel:3606787899"><span><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i></span><strong> (123) 456-7890</strong></a>
      <a href="/contact"><span><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i></span> Send a message</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is jQuery code so far. It works but I am stuck trying to add the fa fa-phone icons and make the phone number clickable.

```
    <script>
$(".jls-agent-name").prepend('<div style="color: #4cae4c; font-weight: bold;">First Person</div><div style="color: #FFF; font-size: 1.5rem; font-weight: bold;">(123) 455-6789 <br></div>');
</script>
```

Comment: I've added an answer for the FontAwesome part. Now tell me what do you mean when you say you want to make the phone no. "clickable"?

Answer (score 1):

**Using jQuery:**

Append your `<link>` into the HTML `<head>`.

```
$('head').append('<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>');
```

Comment: Thanks. This made me think about other ways of doing. I have figured out my problem.

<script>
$(".jls-agent-name").prepend('<div style="color: #4cae4c; font-weight: bold;">First Person</div><div style="color: #FFF; font-size: 1.5rem; font-weight: bold;"><a href="tel:(123) 455-6789"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>(123) 455-6789</a> <br></div>');
</script>